# gerar artefatos de java maven project com parent no Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Gostaria de saber se alguém já gerou package de artefatos de um modulos pelo projeto parent no Jenkins!?
Pois já tentei de todas as formas que pude pensar, mas até agora só obtive erros!
Lembrando que no eclipse ele roda normalmete.

Comment: Pode nos dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Como você está gerando o artefato no jenkins? `mvn clean` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem precisar...
Se o Projeto estiver com todos os módulos dentro da mesma pasta basta ir no "Gerenciamento de código fonte" e lá inserir o endereço do seu repositório no campo "Repository URL";
Se os módulos estiverem em pastas separadas também insira o endereço de cada repositório em um campo "Repository URL" (para acresentar clique em "add module"); Em cada endereço de repositorio escolha o projeto que deseja e adicione o nome do projeto em "Local module directory"
Ficará assim:
Parent
        Repository URL:          endereçocompleto/parent
        Local module directory:  parent
modulo1
Repository URL:                  endereçocompleto/modulo1
        Local module directory:  modulo1

modulo2
        Repository URL:          endereçocompleto/modulo2
        Local module directory:  modulo2

em "construir" adicionar o endereço do pom parent:

Pom Raiz:          parent/pom.xml
Metas e opções:    clean install (use qual quiser)

e clique no botão avançar para adicionar o settings.

Answer (score 0):

No menu Jenkins -> Gerenciar Jenkins -> Configurar o sistema -> configure a JDK, o maven, o e-mail para notificações.

Depois disso, crie um Job no menu Novo Job e escolha "Construir um projeto com Maven". Logo depois de clicar em Ok, selecione o JDK configurado, selecione a opção CVS ou Subversion e preencha o campo Repository URL apontando para o projeto parent. No campo pom raiz basta colocar pom.xml. Nas metas e opções coloque "clean install".

Clique em Salvar e depois clique para no botão para "agendar um build".